# Dual bases in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

Let $f_1,\ldots,f_m \in V^*$ linearly independent. Show that each $1\leq j \leq m$ exists ($v_j$) in $V$ such that $f_i(v_j)=\delta_{ij}$.

I'm using the bidual space and evaluation function to prove  the theorem in the case that $\operatorname{Dim}(V)$ is finite. But the case where $\operatorname{Dim}(V)$ is infinite I can't prove it.

Comment: How does your proof work when the $f_i$ don't span $V^*$? Do the same thing in the infinite-dimensional case. You might want to use the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N$ denote the span of $\{f_1, \dots, f_m\} \subseteq V^*$.  Consider the linear map $\varphi: V \to N^*$ defined by  $\varphi(v)(f) = f(v)$ for $v \in V$ and $f \in N$.  Then $\rm{image}(\varphi) \subseteq N^*$, evidently.  On the other hand, show $N$ imbeds in $\rm{image}(\varphi)^*$.
Conclude that $N$ and $\rm{image}(\varphi)$ have the same (finite) dimension, and hence that $\varphi$ is surjective.  You have now essentially reduced to the finite dimensional case.